# if any parent class based component receive new props but didnt setstate ...is it will call the componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle

i am learning react for last 3 month and didn't get 1 things clearly..i wanted to know that if my top level app component get new props but didn't call any set State...is it gonna call the component Did Mount??or it will not call any component Did Mount..

Comment: Hi Asaduzzaman Himel, it is really hard to get the point of your question. Stackoverflow is not some kind of sub-reddit or forum. We are trying to post valuable questions, that can help thousands of other people. In case you are having trouble with the language, we could try to help you.

Comment: should i have to delete the question?

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski - The question seems clear to me. (Asaduzzaman Himel - It would help if you wrote the names of methods correclty and such, `componentDidMount` rather than "component Did Mount,", etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't call `componentDidMount` again if the component is already mounted, no. But it will (for now) call the old [`componentWillReceiveProps`/`UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), and will call [`render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) and [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

It's easy to try these things out. for example:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Parent - constructor");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Parent - componentDidMount");
    }

    UNSAFE_componentDidReceiveProps() {
        console.log("Parent - UNSAFE_componentDidReceiveProps");
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("Parent - componentDidUpdate");
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Parent - render");
        const { value } = this.props;
        return <Child value={value} />;
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Child - constructor");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Child - componentDidMount");
    }

    UNSAFE_componentDidReceiveProps() {
        console.log("Child - UNSAFE_componentDidReceiveProps");
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("Child - componentDidUpdate");
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Child - render");
        const { value } = this.props;
        return <div>value = {value}</div>;
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                this.setState(({counter}) => {
                    ++counter;
                    if (counter === 2) {
                        clearInterval(this.timer);
                    }
                    return {counter};
                });
            }, 500);
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        const { counter } = this.state;
        return <Parent value={counter} />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```